# Object with z-index child

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a CSS ribbon that uses z-index for its sides. 
http://jsfiddle.net/2nMe9/

[image]

I want to place that object over a container, however, since the depth of the container is assumably set to 0 the margins of the ribbon will not show.
http://jsfiddle.net/Ws4CD/

```
<center><div style="background: black;width: 500px; height:600px;">
<img src="http://m3.i.pbase.com/u45/gaocus/upload/34638653.160x160hawk1301b.jpg" alt="" style="position:absolute;" />
<div id="ribbon">
    <div id="r_content">Text</div>
</div>
```

How can I make the ribbon show completely?

Comment: It's kind of weird to see [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) in a CSS3 project...

Comment: @Passerby I'm more upset by the lack of a `</center>`.

Answer (score 1):

Change z-indexes from negative to positive (see the code). Problem was that background's `z-index` is 0 which is the default value for all elements. So putting z-index under 0 sends your ribbon parts behind that black background.

```
#ribbon {
        padding: .34em 1em;
        width: 129px;
        margin-top: 130px;
        position:relative;
        color: #ffffff;
        font: 16px 'Patua One', sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing:0.1em;
        text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.3),
                    inset 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
                    0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
         background: #1eb2df;
        display: inline-block;
    }

#ribbon:before, #ribbon:after {
        content: "";
        width:.2em;
        bottom:-.5em;
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        border: .9em solid #1eb2df;
        box-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        z-index:0;
    }

#ribbon:before {
        left:-1.35em;
        border-right-width: .75em;
        border-left-color:transparent;
    }

#ribbon:after {
        right:-1.35em;
        border-left-width: .75em;
        border-right-color:transparent;
    }

#r_content:before, #r_content:after {
        content:"";
        bottom:-.5em;
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        border-style:solid;
        border-color: #0675b3 transparent transparent transparent;
        z-index:1;
    }

#r_content:before {
      left: 0;
      border-width: .5em 0 0 .5em;
    }

#r_content:after {
      right: 0;
      border-width: .5em .5em 0 0;
    }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mB3rn/